# Disable ordering

Tags: ordering

I'm attempting to output a list of entries using slug names. When I do the following, the entries are automatically reordered in alphabetical (title) order. Same thing happens if I target the ID's instead of the slugs.

```
{% set menu = craft.entries.slug(['home', 'about', 'services', 'news', 'contact']).order(null).find() %}
{% for entry in menu %}
  {{ entry.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Is there a way to output the list the same way I put it in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try .fixedOrder(), but you might have to query by ID and not slug.

```
.fixedOrder(true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick responce. Didn't seem to work. No errors; just returns an empty array.

Comment: Did you try with the id's `craft.entries.id([3, 2, 1]).fixedOrder(true)`

Comment: Using ID's doesn't do any reordering. Basically does nothing. I thought I'd try another variation of the same thing, but no joy there either: craft.entries({'id':[49, 40, 39, 5, 38]}).fixedOrder(true).find()

Comment: IDK, I've used it in the past... maybe remove .find()

Comment: Dammit... I wasn't seeing anything different because it was being cached! My mistake. You are right though, it works now :) Thank you! Interestingly, removing .find() still works too.